# Convert hour string containing pm to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert a string that contains PM notation to a datetime type. Thanks!

```
datetime.strptime('8/18/2020 11:08:54 PM', '%m/%d%Y %I:%M:%S %p' )
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError: time data '8/18/2020 11:08:54 PM' does not match format '%m/%d%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
```

Comment: You're missing a forward slash between `%d` and `%Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. It's very simple.

```
r = datetime.strptime('8/18/2020 11:08:54 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Or

```
import dateparser

r = dateparser.parse('8/18/2020 11:08:54 PM')
print(r)
```

Comment: Can you provide an answer using the datetime or pandas library?

Comment: @reydonsancho Added an answer with `datetime` only

Comment: You missed "/" in "%m/%d/%Y"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the builtin `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '8/18/2020 11:08:54 PM'
fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)
```